# Querying 'Append Changed to Existing Text' from client script?

Tags: rest, client-object-model

Is there a way, preferably via REST but JSOM would work, to query a SharePoint 2010 field to get all entries when 'Append Changes to Existing Text' on a multiple lines of text field is enabled?